# Classes - Remove a specific object from a vector of objects

Tags: c++, class, oop, inner-classes

I am working on a personal project and I have a `bookshelf class` and `book class`. I am implementing some functions and right now I'm implementing a `remove_book` function that takes a parameter of the title of the book they want removed from the bookshelf.
However I dont know how I would implement that. As an argument you can use any string. You will use the function `get_title` to compare the used argument with titles of elements in the vector and if such an element exists you can remove it from the vector.

I want to avoid loops as much as possible and use some STL algorithms like `remove` and then `erase`. How would this function be implemented in the best way?

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Bookshelf {
 public:
  Bookshelf() {}
  class Book {
   private:
    string title{};
    string author{};
    int pages{};

   public:
    Book(string const& t, string const& a, int const p)
                    : title{t}, author{a}, pages{p}
    {}

    string get_title() const {
      return title;
    }

    void print() const {
      cout << title << ", " << author << ", " << pages << endl;
    }
           
  };

  void add_book(Book const& b) {
    bookshelf.push_back(b);
  }

  void remove_book(string const& choice, vector<Book>& books) {
           // remove(books.begin(), books.end(), ????)
  }

  void print_bookshelf() const {
    for (const auto& e : bookshelf) {
        e.print();  // this will print out our current vector and if we change
        // it will change,
        // instead of creating a copy which is memory consuming
      }
       
  }
 private:
  vector<Book> bookshelf{};
};

int main() {
  Bookshelf::Book book_1("Hej", "Me", 100);
  Bookshelf::Book book_2("Yo", "Me", 150);
  Bookshelf bookshelf_1;

  book_1.print();

  bookshelf_1.add_book(book_1);
  bookshelf_1.add_book(book_2);
  bookshelf_1.print_bookshelf();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `books` parameter is worthless. You're trying to remove a book from the `bookshelf` collection. So do that. Search for the book by linear search evaluating title, and if discovered, remove it from the shelf:

```
void remove_book(string const &choice)
{
    bookshelf.erase(std::find_if(bookshelf.begin(), bookshelf.end(), 
        [&](Book const& b){ return b.get_title() == choice; }));
}
```

This will remove at-most one book whose title matches the `choice` definition.

To remove *all* books with matching title (perhaps you have six copies of the same book on your shelf), a remove/erase idiom is more appropriate:

```
void remove_book(string const &choice)
{
    bookshelf.erase(std::remove_if(bookshelf.begin(), bookshelf.end(), 
        [&](Book const& b){ return b.get_title() == choice; }), bookshelf.end());
}
```

`std::remove_if` works by moving and shifting all elements in the sequence in such a way that the matching elements appear on the "end" of the sequence, then returns an iterator to the *first* element of those that were moved there. An example is worth a thousand words. Suppose we had a sequence of integers that looked like this:

```
1 2 3 2 2 4 5 6 2 3
```

Now supposed we're trying to remove all instances of the value `2`. Using the idiom above, first `std::remove_if` will xform the sequence into this (with the returned iterator marked by `^`):

```
1 3 4 5 6 3 2 2 2 2
            ^
```

Then, the sequence `erase` method is called, using the iterator above, through the end, as the segment to remove. I.e this:

```
1 3 4 5 6 3 2 2 2 2
            -------
```

will be erased, leaving you with:

```
1 3 4 5 6 3
```

Hopefully that explains how remove/erase works.

Comment: Really smart to use a lamba function to solve this problem. Thank you.I will try it out once Im home and see if it will work fine.

The thing Im not really grasping is where in the lambda function do we specify which book we are deleting? I cant really seem to find where it finds the right book

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie The `std::find_if` algorithm searches sequentially over the range `bookshelf.begin()` to `bookshelf.end()`, trying to find the first match where the lambda returns true. If it finds one, an iterator to that object in the sequence is returned, otherwise `bookshelf.end()` is the result. Regardless, `bookshelf.erase` is executed on that iterator to remove the referenced object from the sequence. If it refers to an element, it's gone. if it refers to `bookshelf.end()`, it becomes a no-op.

Comment: Thanks but how does it actually know that the Book we take in the lambda function is in our particular bookshelf?

Comment: Where else would it come from? The only range searched is that of the `bookshelf` member variable. Only books in that vector are considered (and, ultimately deleted if found matching).

Comment: Oh ok gotcha, also could you please maybe add a for_each loop to your function because what if there are duplicates of a specific book? The current function erases at max one book once its called. I suceeded with deleting all occurences of a book with a normal for loop around the function, but I wonder how and where I could put a for_each loop?

Comment: There is no need for a for-each loop. `find_if` is already doing the enumeration over the sequence. If there are duplicate titles *and* you want to delete *all* matching titles you need a different construct (it's called a remove/erase idiom. I can update the answer if you want to see what it looks like. the only reason I did what I showed is because I naively assumed the same book wasn't on the shelf more than once per title.

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks for your updated answer! Appreciate it a lot